# Typescript error: Unsafe assignment of an `any` value on react-select custom component

Tags: typescript, eslint, react-select

I'm trying to give a custom DropdownIndicator to react-select to change the icon if the menu is open or not, but on my DropDownIndicator component it keeps giving me the eslint error of "Unsafe member access .selectProps on an `any` value.", here is my code, someone can help me please?

The error is on the DropdownIndicator in the menuIsOpen part.

```
        import { useState } from "react";
        import Select, { DropdownIndicatorProps } from "react-select";
        import { OverviewTable } from "../components/OverviewTable";
                
        type CustomOptionType = {
          value: string;
          label: string;
        }; 
    
    const DropdownIndicator = ({
          ...props
        }: DropdownIndicatorProps<CustomOptionType, false>) => {
          const {
            selectProps: { menuIsOpen }
          } = props;
        
          if (menuIsOpen) {
            return <i className="fa-solid fa-angle-up text-xs"></i>;
          } else return <i className="fa-solid fa-angle-down text-xs"></i>;
        };


       <Select
            options={options}
            value={selectedUnit}
            onChange={handleChange}
            inputId="unit-select"
            components={{
              IndicatorSeparator: () => null,
              ClearIndicator: () => null,
              DropdownIndicator
            }} 
        />
```

Comment: Returning any is considered a security hole, especially if the return type of the function is explicit.

If you agree with this security hole, you should use a disable comment.

I would use an explicit type assertion, "unknown" or "never"

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#any-unknown-object-void-undefined-null-and-never-assignability

Comment: I can't just disable the line, I am supposed to fix the problem with the type.

Answer (score 0):

You have unnecessary destructuring. Could that be what throws off eslint

```
const DropdownIndicator = ({
  ...props
}: DropdownIndicatorProps<CustomOptionType, false>)
```

Since you are destructuring *all* of the props, this would be equivalent to

```
const DropdownIndicator = (props: DropdownIndicatorProps<CustomOptionType, false>)
```

Since you are further destructuring down to `isMenuOpen`, you could also do that directly:

```
const DropdownIndicator = ({selectProps: {isMenuOpen}}: DropdownIndicatorProps<CustomOptionType, false>)
```

But still, the error is a bit strange. Are you sure your `eslint` is set up properly to lint Typescript?